# Create app from web page

Tags: redmine, openshift

I have a webpage with a link, this link will redirect me to a new instance from my cartridge, for example my link will redirect me to a Redmine application with administration interface, (such connected user have a new instance from redmine) in bakground I will execute in openshift :

```
rhc create app redmine
```

So any ideas how to do that?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you would be better off using the REST API than executing commands: https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/OpenShift/2.0/html/REST_API_Guide/